# Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, foreign-keys

I have a user that has a relationship belongsTo hasMany between, it means a user live in a state, when i want to add a user it gives me error:

> SQLSTATE [23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (ʻaswak`.ʻusers`, CONSTRAINT ʻusers_city_id_foreign `FOREIGN KEY (`city_id`) REFERENCES ʻusers` (ʻid `) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into ʻusers` ( `name`, ʻemail`,` password`,` telephone`,` daten`,` country_id`,` state_id`, ʻautrei`, `city_id` , ʻAutreh`, ʻadressem`, ʻadresser`, ʻimage`, ʻimages`, ʻupdated_at`, `created_at`) values ​​(achraf khazzou, achraf.khazzou@gmail.com, $ 2y $ 10 $ g5qibjlVJqMOlhriu5s / TuS8UIoYEVOYFPHBM4UVa, 0626341177, 1988-06-22, 1, 4?, 7?, hay tihit tinghir, hay tihit tinghir, profiles \ October2020 \ == eyJpdiI6IjJPRVdIUlFcL3VFZm5uM2syK3kra0pBPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6Ik0zZysyY2FIKzZHMWIxZ1hCdnljM2NhZ0lhSllGblBmaXlNUXNcL1NJZDFVPSIsIm1hYyI6IjZkMzBlODdlNjYwNjBiMWRlYmM2MTkxZmMwMDlkNzFjY2NlYjEzOWJiOTg1ZDViMzg2MDZlZDQxY2EwZWNlMjkifQ. jpeg, [ "profiles October2020 \ \ eyJpdiI6IkFlQmljZlFta2RzeFlaZXhGOTZxRWc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiQUlPajV6YkZJd1ZHem90ZGdNT3U1dzFlblV MMTJ6QStIbFwvRE1oYTM5eElBdW1RN0dkcW1xV3RoZWZtXC9MU1lkIiwibWFjIjoiY2YyYzBjMTQ3Zjg1OTcyNjQ1OWY1YjI5MWY4MjBkOTBmZDM3ZWQyMmMyOTQ1ZTg4YjgwMzg0ZjIzMmIwZmFjZiJ9.jpeg "," profiles \ \ October2020 eyJpdiI6IjZnUWVVNEZmR0dHckowV1Erdmlwd0E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiaWdWblYwOG93dlhJVldnaTNDdERjXC9DYmVLUVFxUE9OVlBvWHRyVFdTZWRkVnlwWHkwUXhSeGJGb1BlZmFzSmUiLCJtYWMiOiJkMjlmMGQ4OGIwY2IwYTE0ZDZhNWQ1MzM1YzY5YWRhOWUwNmYwNjNkZmU2ZDhmM2QxMGU1ZTY2YzdlNmQwZTM0In0 = .jpeg "] 2020-10-10 5:32:58 p.m., 2020-10-10 5:32:58 p.m.)).

States Table

[image]

City Table

[image]

Sometimes it gives me error CONSTRAINT `users_city_id_foreign` and sometimes CONSTRAINT `users_state_id_foreign`, knowing that the tables states and city are folded by states and cities

**User.php**

```
public function country() { 
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Country'); 
}

public function state() { 
    return $this->belongsTo('App\State');  
}

public function city() { 
    return $this->belongsTo('App\City'); 
}
```

**City.php**

```
public function users(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\User'); 
}
```

**State.php**

```
public function users(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
}
```

**users table**

```
$table->bigInteger('country_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
$table->foreign('country_id')->references('id') 
          ->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
$table->bigInteger('city_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
$table->foreign('city_id')->references('id') 
          ->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
$table->string('autreh')->nullable();
$table->bigInteger('state_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
$table->foreign('state_id')->references('id') 
          ->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. This is a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 0):

your foreign key reference is wrong. you reference the key of the parent table, not the table itself in foreign key declaration. change your migration file

```
$table->bigInteger('country_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
$table->foreign('country_id')->references('id') 
          ->on('countries')->onDelete('cascade');
$table->bigInteger('city_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
$table->foreign('city_id')->references('id') 
          ->on('cities')->onDelete('cascade');
$table->string('autreh')->nullable();
$table->bigInteger('state_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
$table->foreign('state_id')->references('id') 
          ->on('states')->onDelete('cascade');
```

i have assumed your table names, change according to your's if needed. migrate again and this will work.

Comment: thx for u answer but its give me error  `1215 Impossible d'ajouter des contraintes d'index externe (SQL: alter table users add constraint users_country_id_fo
reign foreign key (country_id) references countries (id) on delete cascade)`

Comment: a index already exists with the same name from the previous migrate.. you have to delete those